WPF ComboBox with ListView Item Binding
I've seen what looks like 100s of questions on how to implement a ComboBox inside of a ListView, but never a ListView inside of a ComboBox. Is this possible?
The closest I've gotten is inserting the ListView directly as a ComboBoxItem, which looks great visually.

However, this has horrible repercussions when it comes to displaying the Selected Item. When selecting a List View Item, it basically shoves the whole ListView into the ComboBox dropdown text area.

See code below:
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="0.6*" Header="Ring Set" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderWrap}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <ListView Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding RingSets}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Ring Set" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Ring Set Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

I've also tried setting the ItemContainerStyle of the ComboBox like this:
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="0.6*" Header="Ring Set" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderWrap}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding RingSets}">
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ListView>
                                        <ListView.View>
                                            <GridView>
                                                <GridViewColumn Header="Ring Set" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}">
                                                </GridViewColumn>
                                                <GridViewColumn Header="Ring Set Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}">
                                                </GridViewColumn>
                                            </GridView>
                                        </ListView.View>
                                    </ListView>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

I've been unable to get the items to display properly with this version:

BUT if I click barely under the header I can manage to select an item and it does at least display the dictionary entry (which I could format to pull out the key or whatever to display).

So I have kind of 2 half working solutions, but neither fully what I want. Any insight would be great!

You are looking for a MultiColumnComboBox - there are some 3rd party controls out in the field

Does this answer your question? WPF ComboBox Multiple Columns

@Orace it is a possible solution - though it doesn't look as nice as an actual ListView. I was hoping to use an actual ListView inside of the ComboBox, that way it can use headers and have built in highlighting on hover (though the highlighting can be solved via triggers I think).
